# Chrome - stop shift+enter from creating a new chrome window from a password field

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, hotkeys

Is it possible to do this?

My problem is some of my passwords end in an upper-case letter or a special character that requires the SHIFT key to be held down. When I finish typing and press ENTER, I end up pressing shift+enter which causes a new chrome window to pop up.

I like Chrome but this is very annoying.

Comment: I just entered this comment, now hit SHIFT_ENTER --> no new window for me. Where are you seeing this behaviour ?

Comment: @SathyajithBhat in the URL bar

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue on my Mac using the app Keyboard Maestro. From within Keyboard Maestro, I created a Chrome-specific shortcut that makes "shift+return" (i.e., "shift+enter") execute a simple return/enter (i.e., as if shift hadn't been pressed). Works like a charm.

(I'm guessing similar software is available for Windows and other OS's, but I don't know for sure.)

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine had a similar problem so I whipped up [this Chrome userscript](https://gist.github.com/2799464) for him. The way it works is if you are in a password field and press SHIFT+ENTER it will stop the keypress event from propagating and instead try to submit the form.

To install to Chrome click on the "raw" link in github or [click here](https://gist.github.com/raw/2799464/6a2d53be147e833e510bba763142a88362235f67/shiftenter_blocker.user.js)
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/), you can create a keyboard shortcut for shift+enter and have it map to enter. This will override the Chrome behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with better touch tool to make shift enter = enter but now I realized that it I do want shift enter to work in chrome when writing in a text box to go down a line instead of a paragraph, or in Facebook for instance to go down a paragraph instead of submitting my comment, so now I need to use function shift enter to go down a paragraph which is not ideal. Would be good if chrome had an option to simply disable this without the need of a workaround.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).